# Regular expression to capture first n digits from comma separated strings

Tags: regex

I quickly found a way to get a working multi-line regular expression for my needs, but having trouble with its conversion into a single line.

So, consider this input with regex `/^[2-9]\d{1}(?:\s){0}/gm` applied:

**41**26-54D429-001,

**51**49-A42102-002,

**92**51-Z48910-003
...

However, when I turn it to one line, I'm getting only first two digits in ouput:

**41**26-54D429-001, 5149-A42102-002, 9251-Z48910-003 ...

How can this regexp be written to get this capture:

**41**26-54D429-001, **51**49-A42102-002, **92**51-Z48910-003 ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This Should Work.*

**REGEXP**

```
\b\d{2}(?=\d{2})
```

**INPUT**

```
4126-54D429-001, 5149-A42102-002, 9251-Z48910-003, 7851-Z48910-003
```

**OUTPUT**

```
41
51
92
78
```

**The comma is not essential**

*If i help u, mark me as correct and vote up*

Answer (score 0):

This will capture the first two digits of each in groups:

`(\d{2})[^,]*`

Comment: Nice answer, but it only match numbers when comma is present.

Comment: Yeah, but isn't each entry separated by a comma? Please see the demo here: https://regex101.com/r/3zuMg8/1

Comment: Sorry, but regexr.com gives me this output: **4126-54D429-001**, **5149-A42102-002**, **9251-Z48910-003**

Comment: and tailing `*` also produce redudant characters (spaces, newline, etc.)

Comment: You are looking at the full match. This works with capture groups.